# Clear button should not required field HTML5

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, button

im creating the form include below code :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" required="required" runat="server" placeholder="Phone No. (eg. 999)"
                    CssClass="glowStyle"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddDriver" Text="Add" runat="server" CssClass="button" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCnclAddDriver" Text="Clear" runat="server" 
        CssClass="cancelbutton" onclick="btnCnclAddDriver_Click" />
    </form>
```

when i click the "Clear" button, the required (html5) still show up.
how to disable it for Clear button only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `formnovalidate` attribute to your cancel/clear button.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp) you can find some more information about this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually require a server control to cancel ? A simple `<input type="reset">` or a small javascript code can do the job in most situations.

<s>If not, simple add `CauseValidation="false"` to your button :</s>

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCnclAddDriver" CauseValidation="false" Text="Clear" runat="server" 
    CssClass="cancelbutton" onclick="btnCnclAddDriver_Click" />
```

(remove suggestion as it applies to asp.net validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your TextBox(s) with javascript (jQuery) :

```
$('txtPhone').val('');
```

Or Javascript :

```
   function name()
   {  
       document.getElementById('txtPhone').value = "";
   }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the autopostback option for btnCnclAddDriver button to False. And execute your server side code (btnCnclAddDriver_Click) by Ajax.